# How to check data available or not in table using django query?

Tags: django, python-3.x

We have one table and using **django orm query** we have to check that data is available or not in table. So my question is using orm query and if,else conditions we have to show.

Answer (score 3):

There are two way to check.
1). filter()
2). get()

```
user = User.objects.filter(pk/user_id = "12345")
```

It will give you the list of user if user does not exist it will empty list.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk = "12345")
```

It will give the object if user exist, if does not exist then it will give you an error "Object does not exist".
If you use filter you can just check

```
try:
   if not user:
        return
except Exception, e:
    raise or something return
```

If you use get if user does not exist then it will automatically raise exception "Object Does Not Exist"

Answer (score 1):

Best way is using [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
YourModel.objects.all().exists()  # returns a boolean value

# or

YourModel.objects.filter(some_key=some_value).exists()

# Usage
if queryset.exists():
    # do something
```

But if you know that queryset will be [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) at some point, then using `exists()` will create more overall work. In that case, its better to use `bool(queryset)`.